# Angular mat-icon doesn't show the icon

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, icons

I'm trying to use mat-icon but it doesn't work properly. I have a table and inside a data cell I'm trying to use a mat-icon. The problem is that it doesn't the show icon but is showing the name. I included import { MatIconModule } from "@angular/material/icon" in app.module.ts
e.g: clear => it's showing: clear
My code:

````
<div class="mat-elevation-z8 layout-container">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Index">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.rowspan]="2">No.</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">{{ i + 1 }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Icon">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Icon</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><mat-icon>clear</mat-icon></td>
    </ng-container>
</table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements"> </mat-paginator>
</div>```
````

Comment: try importing font - `@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';` or by link- `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your `index.html` the following

```
    <!-- material icons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```